# creating DateTime using constructor changes time

Tags: php

I am converting a PHP 5.4 project to PHP 7.4.6.
When I create a new instance of DateTime, the time is changing.
Why is this happening?

```
public function testNewDateTime()
{
  $this->assertEquals('UTC', date_default_timezone_get());
  $value = new \DateTime('2018-03-11 02:15:00', new \DateTimeZone('America/Winnipeg'));
  $this->assertEquals('2018-03-11 02:15:00', $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}

Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :'2018-03-11 02:15:00'
Actual   :'2018-03-11 03:15:00'
```

Comment: Daylight savings time...

Comment: Well, what's your timezone? Also, if this is a unit test you probably want it to pass independent of what timezone the machine is in, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nick. 2018-03-11 2:15 is an invalid date/time because of daylight savings time so it changes to the next hour.